# Failed to fetch for all repositories, but internet connection is fine

Tags: 14.04, updates

I am using an 14.09 Ubuntu version. When I update system to 16.04 I get the error

> A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

But my connection is stable and I am using main server, so what could the problem be?

```
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: @karel i tried to switch servers, but it doesn't helps. And "original" question doesn't have good answer too, so

Comment: Is your machine architecture really arm64, or did you add that as a foreign architecture (for cross compiling, for example)? Anyhow, AFAIK the arm64 repos have been moved to a separate "ports" site e.g. `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/`

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 14.09.  What hardware do you have? Please add output of `uname -a`, `cat /etc/os-release` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your version of Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10? Your question states that you are trying to upgrade Ubuntu 14.09.
Ubuntu only allows you to jump intermediate versions when upgrading LTS to LTS (14.04 to 16.04).
If you are upgrading from 14.10 (which is no longer supported) you would need to upgrade to 15.04 then 15.10 then 16.04. If that is the case it would be easier to simply do a fresh install of 16.04.